# mx:List itemrenderer acces value

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a mx:list with custom itemrenderer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%"
         horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
         >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Placer ici les éléments non visuels (services et objets de valeur, par exemple). -->


    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[


/* part with no warning 
[Bindable] var tName:String;
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    acID.text = value.id;
    acGlob.text = value.glob;
    acVisiO.text = value.visibO;
    acVisiV.text = value.visibV;
    acRoot.text = value.root;
    //acPhoto.source = value.photo;
    //acName.text = value.name;
    tName = value.name
}
override public function get data():Object
{
return super.data;
} */
]]>
</fx:Script>
    <mx:states>
        <mx:State name="normal"/>
        <mx:State name="hovered"/>
        <mx:State name="selected"/>

    </mx:states>

    <mx:Image source="{data.photo}" width="20" height="20" alpha.hovered=".5"/>
    <mx:Label text="{data.name}" 
              color.hovered="0x1313cd" color.selected="0x000000" color.normal="#000000"
              toolTip="{data.name}"
              />
    <mx:Label  visible="false" width="0" height="0" id="acID" />
    <mx:Label visible="false" width="0" height="0" id="acGlob"/>
    <mx:Label  visible="false" width="0" height="0" id="acVisiO"/>
    <mx:Label  visible="false" width="0" height="0" id="acVisiV"/>
    <mx:Label visible="false" width="0" height="0" id="acRoot" />


</mx:HBox>
```

If I use set data function, no warning appear. But in this case I don't know how to access on itemrenderer data on doublickclik.

```
arrList = new ArrayList(list);
listAcc = new List();
listAcc.percentHeight = 100;
listAcc.percentWidth =100;
listAcc.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(irMxList);
listAcc.doubleClickEnabled = true;
listAcc.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_DOUBLE_CLICK, onItemDoubleClick);
listAcc.dataProvider = arrList;
```

My problem is that an error appear if  I try to access on itemrenderer.data

```
private function onItemDoubleClick(event:ListEvent):void {

            var label:String =  event.itemRenderer.data.name;
            var index:String = event.itemRenderer.data.id;
            var glob:String = event.itemRenderer.data.glob;
            var visuO:String = event.itemRenderer.data.visibO;
            var visuV:String = event.itemRenderer.data.visibV;
            var rootFile:String = event.itemRenderer.data.root;
```

}

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

```
private function onItemDoubleClick(event:ListEvent):void {
      var data:Object = arrList.getItemAt(event.rowIndex);

      var label:String =  data.name;
      var index:String = data.id;
      var glob:String = data.glob;
      var visuO:String = data.visibO;
      var visuV:String = data.visibV;
      var rootFile:String = data.root;
}
```

Comment: I try this answer and this error appear ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 2 not found on mx.collections.ArrayList and there is no default value.

Answer (score 0):

Find below a solution

```
private function onItemDoubleClick(event:ListEvent):void {

                var label:String =  event.itemRenderer.data.name;
                var index:String = event.itemRenderer.data.id;
                var glob:String = event.itemRenderer.data.glob;
                var visuO:String = event.itemRenderer.data.visibO;
                var visuV:String = event.itemRenderer.data.visibV;
                var rootFile:String = event.itemRenderer.data.root; }
```

ItemRenderer code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%"
         horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
         >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Placer ici les éléments non visuels (services et objets de valeur, par exemple). -->


    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private var _data:Object;

            override public function set data(value:Object):void {
                acID.text = value.id;
                acGlob.text = value.glob;
                acVisiO.text = value.visibO;
                acVisiV.text = value.visibV;
                acRoot.text = value.root;
                acPhoto.source = value.photo;
                acName.text = value.name;
                _data = value;

            }

            override public function get data():Object {
                return _data;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:states>
        <mx:State name="normal"/>
        <mx:State name="hovered"/>
        <mx:State name="selected"/>

    </mx:states>

    <!--<mx:Image source="{data.photo}" width="20" height="20" alpha.hovered=".5"/>
    <mx:Label text="{data.name}"
              color.hovered="0x1313cd" color.selected="0x000000" color.normal="#000000"
              toolTip="{data.name}"
              />-->

    <mx:Image id="acPhoto" width="20" height="20" alpha.hovered=".5"/>
    <mx:Label id="acName"
              color.hovered="0x1313cd" color.selected="0x000000" color.normal="#000000"
              toolTip="{acName.text}"
              />
    <mx:Label  visible="false" width="0" height="0" id="acID" />
    <mx:Label visible="false" width="0" height="0" id="acGlob"/>
    <mx:Label  visible="false" width="0" height="0" id="acVisiO"/>
    <mx:Label  visible="false" width="0" height="0" id="acVisiV"/>
    <mx:Label visible="false" width="0" height="0" id="acRoot" />


</mx:HBox>
```

Thanks everybody